# Unable To get property 'parentNode' in one of three DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I currently have 3 DataTables on a page within tabs. 2 of these work fine, however, one does not and produces the error:

`Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference`

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
    <img src="~/Content/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Search Loading Animation" id="self-approve-search-loading-anim" class="ajax-anim search-box-anim" />
    <table id="self-approval-table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Department
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Telephone
                </th>
                <th>
                    Job Title
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is my initialisation code:

```
$('a[href="#tabs-2"]').on('click', function(){
        var table = $('#self-approval-table');
        if(!$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(table)){
            searchAnim = $('#self-approve-search-loading-anim');
            url = serviceEndpoint + 'api/Users/SelfApproval';
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#self-approval-table').DataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        'aoColumns': [
                            {
                                'mDataProp': 'Department'
                            },
                            {
                                'mDataProp': 'UserName'
                            },
                            {
                                'mDataProp': 'Email'
                            },
                            {
                                'mDataProp': 'Telephone'
                            },
                            {
                                'mDataProp': 'JobTitle'
                            }
                        ],
                        'aaData': data
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    if (searchAnim != null) {
                        searchAnim.hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I have tried many things, using the new and old initialisation methods as well as altering the fields. The data is returned correctly from my ajax call and the properties line up correctly with the values entered into aoColumns -> mDataProp.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this thread which might or might not be relevant: https://github.com/DataTables/FixedColumns/issues/21. What happens if you call table.Destroy() before the Ajax call for data, instead of using the destroy option in your initialization?

Comment: @Adam unfortunately that didnt change anything and i still come across the same error.